# ngfor for array in object with ng2-charts

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to use ng2-charts to plot many graphs. I am using `ngFor` to loop inside my array and make as many plot as my array got.

Actually I have an array like that :

```
   full_graph =  [
    {
    data : [2,4],
    labels: ['oct','nov']
    },
    {
    data : [2,4],
    labels: ['oct','nov']
    }
    ]
```

So I should have 2 graphs (line charts actually).

In my html file :

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let data of full_graph">
    <ion-card *ngFor= 'let d of data'>
        {{d.data}}
        {{d.labels}}
        <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
        [datasets]="d.data"
        [labels]="d.labels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
        [plugins]="lineChartPlugins"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
      </canvas>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-list>
```

When I display, `d.data` and `d.labels` in the ionic card it works, I have 2 cards with my data. But inside `<canvas>` where I put `d.data` and `d.labels` I got an error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

If instead d.data and d.labels inside the canvas I give 2 simples array it works perfectly, so I do not get why I can not do it..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here -

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of full_graph">
  <ion-card *ngFor= 'let d of data'>
```

You are trying to take 'data' as array instead as an object, because full_graph is an array of objects not an array of arrays, so you can fix that replacing above code using below -

```
 <ion-list>
   <ion-card *ngFor="let d of full_graph">
```

Comment: I have tried it before, and it does not work. I got this : ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line
    at BaseChartDirective.getDatasets (ng2-charts.js:863). With my double ngFor, I can display my value inside the ion-card with my {{d.data}} => this work but inside the canvas it does not..

Comment: do you have any variable named 'data' in the component.ts file ?

Comment: I have a local variable inside a function called data

Comment: Did you tried changing the variable name data to something else in *ngFor loop ?
it is a bit confusing to me, why you need 2 *ngFor loop for this case !

Comment: Yes I did, it was for me too but it’s i can display data... don’t get why I can display it and not plot it..

Comment: Did you find any solution ?